# Set custom ScrollViewer property value with AttachedProperty

Tags: wpf, xaml

I retemplated TreeView with my custom ScrollViewer. If I try to set AttachedProperty "ScrollViewer.PanningMode" of TreeView in code-behind, then my custom ScrollViewer doesn't seem to change (PanningMode of ScrollViewer stays the same).

Code-behind:

```
_treeView.SetValue(ScrollViewer.PanningModeProperty, PanningMode.None);
```

**EDIT**

Actually, I solved it like this:

```
ScrollViewer scrollViewer = _treeView.Template.FindName("ScrollViewer", _treeView) as ScrollViewer;
if (scrollViewer != null)
    scrollViewer.PanningMode = PanningMode.None;
```

But it is not very beautiful and doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Try TemplateBinding PanningMode in your custom scrollviewer's ControlTemplate as follows.
PanningMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.PanningMode}"

Comment: @VictoryJessie ScrollViewer should already support TemplateBinding to TemplatedParent's Attached Properties.

Comment: @IlyaSolovyev What is the old value of panning mode in your case before trying to change it?

Comment: maybe posting more of your code here could help

Comment: @devhedgehog Old value is the value I specify in xaml in design-mode (e.g. PanningMode.Both).